# Add Axioms of Expression Editor using OWLAPI

Tags: owl, owl-api

I have an API that receive a JSON document with classes, properties and axioms of an ontology. The file looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "https://onto4alleditor.com/pt/idDoProjeto",
    "filetype": "OWL",
    "classes": [{
                    "Name": "Homem",
                    "SubClassOf": ["Pessoa"],
                    "DisjointWith": ["Mulher"],
                    "Annotation": [{"Annotation":"Homo sapiens do sexo masculino.", "Language":"pt"},
                                   {"Annotation": "Male homo sapiens.", "Language": "en"}]
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Mulher",
                    "Constraint": ["Mulher EquivalentTo: (NOT Homem)"],
                    "SubClassOf": ["Pessoa"]
                }
                ]
 }
```

The variable **Constraint** is an expression obtained from the Expression Editor of the Protegé. I'm trying to to add this expression to my OWLOntology object, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
Encountered Mulher at line 1 column 1. Expected one of:
    Class name
    Object property name
    Data property name
    inv
    Functional
    inverse
    InverseFunctional
    (
    Asymmetric
    Transitive
    Irreflexive
    {
    Symmetric
    Reflexive
```

Mulher is a class of my ontology, thus the error doesn't make sense. I'm not sure why this is happening, as I believe my code is initializing the parser properly (I'm using the Manchester Parser to do the job).Here follows my code:

```
private void loadClassConstraints(JSONArray constraints){
    ManchesterOWLSyntaxParser parser = OWLManager.createManchesterParser();
    parser.setDefaultOntology(this.ont);
    for (int i = 0; i < constraints.length(); i++) {
        parser.setStringToParse(constraints.getString(i));
        this.ont.add(parser.parseAxiom());
    }
}
```

What is going wrong? I couldn't find enough documentation on the internet which applies to my problem.Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that parsing the axiom relies on an OWLEntityChecker implementation to convert strings to class or property expressions, in this case `Mulher` to the entity as declared in your ontology, e.g., `urn:test:Mulher`.

There is an example on how to configure this in the OWLAPI tracker:
https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/507

Protege uses a similar mechanism but it has its own OWLEntityChecker implementations, which wouldn't be available to you if you're only using OWLAPI.

The example below uses a naive implementation of OWLEntityChecker which will use the fragment of the IRIs for all entities in the ontology to identify the entities; this is limited, because in real ontologies the IRI fragments can easily clash or be missing. However it might help, if the example on the bug tracker isn't good enough.

```
    OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLDataFactory df = m.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLOntology ont = m.createOntology(IRI.create("urn:test:test"));
    ont.add(df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(df.getOWLClass("urn:test:Mulher")));
    ont.add(df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(df.getOWLClass("urn:test:Homem")));
    ManchesterOWLSyntaxParser parser = OWLManager.createManchesterParser();
    parser.setDefaultOntology(ont);
    final Map<String, OWLEntity> map = new HashMap<>();
    ont.signature().forEach(x -> map.put(x.getIRI().getFragment(), x));
    parser.setOWLEntityChecker(new OWLEntityChecker() {
        private <T> T v(String name, Class<T> t) {
            OWLEntity e = map.get(name);
            if (t.isInstance(e)) {
                return t.cast(e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public OWLObjectProperty getOWLObjectProperty(String name) {
            return v(name, OWLObjectProperty.class);
        }

        @Override
        public OWLNamedIndividual getOWLIndividual(String name) {
            return v(name, OWLNamedIndividual.class);
        }

        @Override
        public OWLDatatype getOWLDatatype(String name) {
            return v(name, OWLDatatype.class);
        }

        @Override
        public OWLDataProperty getOWLDataProperty(String name) {
            return v(name, OWLDataProperty.class);
        }

        @Override
        public OWLClass getOWLClass(String name) {
            return v(name, OWLClass.class);
        }

        @Override
        public OWLAnnotationProperty getOWLAnnotationProperty(String name) {
            return v(name, OWLAnnotationProperty.class);
        }
    });
    parser.setStringToParse("Mulher EquivalentTo: (NOT Homem)");
    OWLAxiom parseAxiom = parser.parseAxiom();
    System.out.println("of.main() " + parseAxiom);
    ont.add(parseAxiom);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Ignazio. The solution you provided works for now. But as you said, in the real context may be not enough. But I shall see in the future. :)